# Detect network roaming when there is no Internet connection

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I would like to detect network roaming, while there is not Internet connection on Windows Phone 8 and 8.1. I used this code to determine if user is in roaming:

```
ConnectionProfile profile = Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
        if (profile == null)
            return false;
        else
            return profile.GetConnectionCost().Roaming;
```

With this code it is easy to find if a phone is in roaming when there is an Internet access. However the problem occurs when there is not the connection and the ConnectionProfile returns null. I searched the Internet and Stack Overflow for detecting network roaming, but without results. It was suggested to use MNC and MCC, but the Windows Phone doesn't provide such information or any more detailed network info. I didn't find either a function like Android telephonyManager.isNetworkRoaming().

Is there a function, API or method to detect that user is in roaming, but when the Internet connection is down?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this,

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation;
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("Network available:  ");
    sb.AppendLine(DeviceNetworkInformation.IsNetworkAvailable.ToString());
    sb.Append("Cellular enabled:  ");
    sb.AppendLine(DeviceNetworkInformation.IsCellularDataEnabled.ToString());
    sb.Append("Roaming enabled:  ");
    sb.AppendLine(DeviceNetworkInformation.IsCellularDataRoamingEnabled.ToString());
    sb.Append("Wi-Fi enabled:  ");
    sb.AppendLine(DeviceNetworkInformation.IsWiFiEnabled.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
}
```

You may also find this useful http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj207005%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: This library is known to me, but it is not exactly what I want. From this I can only know that if user allowed phone to make connections (WiFi, GSM etc), but does not inform if it is really in roaming.

Comment: DeviceNetworkInformation.IsCellularDataRoamingEnabled.ToString() this doesn't work??

Comment: When you turn off data roaming this property will give you false. In order to determine if it is roaming when there is Internet connection I use connection profile described in a link in your answer. The catch is to determine roaming without available Internet.